# Plugins + Extensions on Safari 5.0.1

Tags: plugins, safari, npapi

My question is very simple: Is it possible to pack plugins into extensions for Safari? For instance, the exact NPAPI plugins which work on Google Chrome also work on Safari. However in Chrome I'm shipping the plugins as a part of an extension (a CRX package). This is needed because HTML and JavaScript is injected into a specific web page, and this code uses the plugins. I do not see an option in Extension Builder to specify plugin files and I haven't come across any proper documentation saying that plugins cannot be packed into extensions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that is supported. A workaround could be a custom installer that installs both the plugin and the extension.

Comment: Yes, I just about figured the same thing after this long :). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first comment:

*I don't think that is supported. A workaround could be a custom installer that installs both the plugin and the extension. – Georg Fritzsche*

This is the only possible way to do it! FYI: Apple guys are against the idea of extensions accessing native code (ie, plugins). An obvious security loop-hole, but a necessity here! :)